# angular archwizard how to change stepIndex

Tags: angular

angular arch wizard  how to change step Index 
I am working with two form on same page how to change step Index 
so i can go to that particular step
angular arch wizard  how to change step Index 
I am working with two form on same page how to change step Index 
so i can go to that particular step

```
<aw-wizard >
    <aw-wizard-step  >
        <form role="form" >
            <div >
                <label class="text-left">Enter Email or Mobile to Login</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter email and phone number" type="text" >
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button  type="submit"  >Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </aw-wizard-step>
    <aw-wizard-step >
        <form role="form" >
            <div class="first-s" id="phone">
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label class="text-left">Enter Verification Code</label>
                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="code" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button  type="submit" >Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </aw-wizard-step>
    <aw-wizard-step>
        <form role="form" >
            <div class="second-s" >
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label class="text-left">Enter Password</label>
                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="">
                </div>
                <button  type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </aw-wizard-step>
</aw-wizard>
```

Comment: Have you... check the documentation? https://github.com/madoar/angular-archwizard#awgotostep

Comment: yes i check  i <aw-wizard-step [stepId]='5> and then i call <button [awGoToStep]="{ stepId: 5 }">

Comment: but it not working

Comment: by default step start from 0 but i want to change the step id

Answer (score 2):

First you have to define a unique Id for each step with [stepId] and then on where you want to perform the jump action you use [awGoToStep] = "{stepId: stepId}"